# Why there's any voltage on P-N junction in diodes?

Tags: voltage, light-emitting-diodes

If all electrons here have their counterparts in protons, on both, P and N sides, then why there's any voltage (built-in voltage, on the bottom of the image)?
Both sides should be neutral, shouldn't they?

[image: p-n junction in diodes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, what you claim is true for the electric field. In order to determine the voltage you then integrate the (opposite of the) electric field along a path. Since in the pictures the electric field is non-positive, the potential builds-up as contribution of opposite of a negative electric field along the diode.